# display a menu bar icon on osx

Tags: python, macos

I'd like to have my application display an icon in OSX menu bar (top of screen where Growl sits).  How would I do this using Python?  (I understand this is not possible using wxPython but I am **not** after a wxPython specific solution).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation of this may be found at:

https://web.archive.org/web/20080709014939/http://the.taoofmac.com/space/blog/2007/04/22/1745

http://the.taoofmac.com/space/blog/2007/04/22/1745

Comment: This page seems to be gone now.  Is it possible to get an update?  (It always helps to cut and paste into an answer key points, in case something like this happens.)

Comment: Archive.org and Google's cache are always good things to try checking. I don't want to copy and paste a large answer. There may also be copyright considerations. I've updated the answer to include an archive.org'd link to it.

Answer (score 1):

The API for displaying icons in the OS X menubar is called [`NSStatusItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's going to be difficult or impossible to use from a wxPython application, though -- you will probably have to write your application using PyObjC to use it effectively.

Comment: ...and how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The [rumps](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps) package makes this very easy. Here's an example from rumps's README:

```py
import rumps

class AwesomeStatusBarApp(rumps.App):
    @rumps.clicked("Preferences")
    def prefs(self, _):
        rumps.alert("jk! no preferences available!")

    @rumps.clicked("Silly button")
    def onoff(self, sender):
        sender.state = not sender.state

    @rumps.clicked("Say hi")
    def sayhi(self, _):
        rumps.notification("Awesome title", "amazing subtitle", "hi!!1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AwesomeStatusBarApp("Awesome App").run()
```

[image: rumps example application]